# I'm going to Installing elementary OS on primary partition. will that effect my other partition?

Tags: system-installation, files

I'm using windows 10 with 2 partitions. if i install eOS instead of windows will that put my other personal data partition on danger. Please answer sooner.

Answer (score 0):

First, you better try with elementary OS live CD to check out if it will work well on your computer. If you install the elementary os on the partition that you do not have any data to keep - it should not put in danger the other partitions where you have data to keep because elementary os file manager can read windows partitions also. But if it is possible - **make a backup of all your files you want to keep** - anyone with experince of this will advice you to do that.

Comment: thank you bro. is rufus good for creating bootable usb device? what shold i select gpd or mrb?

Comment: @Nishanth [Installation instructions](https://elementary.io/docs/installation#installation) recommend using rufus, and choosing MBR